# When the data and encoding are known to be valid, what other reason could cause NSString initWithData to return nil?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In [the reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1416374-initwithdata) for [NSString initWithData:encoding:] it says,-

"Returns nil if the initialization fails for some reason (for example if data does not represent valid data for encoding)"

I know the data and encoding are correct, because the data was returned by [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsjsonserialization/1413636-datawithjsonobject?language=objc), so it must be valid and it must be UTF8

My question is:

***What other reason could cause NSString initWithData to return nil?***

I have researched this extensively and only found answers that suggest the data and/or encoding may be invalid, but I have checked and these are definitely correct.

My code is very similar to the following:

```
NSData* data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:array 
                                               options:0 
                                                 error:nil];
if (!data) return nil;

NSString* string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data 
                                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

array must be valid because data is not nil

data must be valid & UTF8 because it was returned by NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject

*I cannot post my data because it is proprietary* which should not matter for the reasons given

***What other reason could cause NSString initWithData to return nil?***

Comment: I still tend to think there's something wrong with your json array. If you cannot post your data can you make a little copy of your array which is similar to original and reproduces the problem and post it here?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that `data` is not nil?

Comment: @AndreyChernukha According to the reference for NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject; An exception would be thrown if the array wouldn't produce a valid JSON object. It only returns a valid UTF8 encoded JSON data object or nil

Comment: @Cristik The line `if (!data) return nil;` ensures that data is not nil

Comment: I would really very much appreciate if someone could answer the question:
"*Given that we know the data is valid and the encoding is correct*, **what other reason could cause NSString initWithData to return nil?**"

Comment: Check if you are using right encoding. Means string is encrypted with utf-16 and you might be using utf-8 for decoding. Also make sure that data is not corrupted.

Comment: @Satyam The encoding is definitely correct because it is returned from NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject. I suppose the data could get corrupted by memory resource issues